# Worksheet Function Vlookup not returning anything

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that returns "valid" if the product is found in the master data sheet and "invalid" if not found. I am using the worksheet function vlookup to do this.

Below is the code:

```
Sub fg_type()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ref_wb As Workbook
Dim ref_ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ref_lastRow As Long

Dim lookup_val As Variant
Dim table_arr As Variant
Dim fgtype As Variant

Set wb = Workbooks("un_orders.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("uo")
Set ref_wb = Workbooks("target.xlsx")
Set ref_ws = ref_wb.Worksheets("Document")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
ref_lastRow = ref_ws.Cells(ref_ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

table_arr = ref_ws.Range("G3:G" & ref_lastRow)

For i = 2 To lastRow
    lookup_val = ws.Range("C" & i).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    fgtype = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup_val, table_arr, 1, False)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        fgtype(i, 1) = "valid"
    Else
        fgtype(i, 1) = "invalid"
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & i).Value = fgtype(i, 1)
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

However, after running the code, all returns were blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Due to your `On Error Resume Next`, you're not seeing that fgtype(i,1) would throw an error (VLookup isn't returning an array) and so ws.Range("A" & i).Value isn't getting anything as this line also throws an error. Try removing the error catching there and for the if use the `If Not IsError(fgtype)`

Comment: Why `VLookup` instead of `Match`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "valid"
    Else
        ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "invalid"
    End If
Next i
On Error Goto 0
```

Always disable custom error handling when not necessary, because it hides error messages as Notus_Panda commented.

Comment: This would make every cell "valid" as there won't be an `Err` raised whilst putting an error value in the Variant variable.